# Read multiple responses from TCP Socket

Tags: node.js

I am trying to query an INSTEON home automation server using a js net socket.
When I connect interactively and send a status query via the console I get two packets back:

```
Connected to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9761
02621FE3E80f1900   <-- typed into console
Send: 02621FE3E80f1900    
Rsvd: 02621fe3e80f190006    
Rsvd: 02501fe3e81ec00a2f0000
quit              <-- typed into console
Connection closed
```

The second one arrives about half a second after the first.

However, when I try to send the message inside the js script, using:  **client.write('02621FE3E80f1900','hex');**   I only get the first message back:

```
Connected to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9761
Rsvd: 02621fe3e80f190006
Connection closed
```

How can I get access to both messages?

I need the first message to confirm my query was received successfully, 
and the second message in a string so I can interrogate it...

John

Comment: If you were literally typing hex characters (and not the binary counterparts they represent) in the first example, you don't want to specify `hex` encoding for `write()` because that converts the literal hex characters to their binary representation.

Comment: The write() part works fine. I know the server is receiving the correct message.  The problem I have is getting the full reply. I only get the first part.  Do you know how I can get both parts?